# how to migrate several web apps and databases from AWS to Azure

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, azure, nginx, amazon-redshift

we're using Redshift and have several web app and database we're planning to Migrate to Azure.
So not able to find the right proper documents or steps to follow. can someone please help me with this.

Comment: Can you provide more details, like what apps and database ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the method you can use which is migrate Amazon Web Services (AWS) virtual machines (VMs) to Azure VMs by using Azure Site Recovery. When you migrate AWS EC2 instances to Azure, the VMs are treated like physical, on-premises computers

Comment: Thanks, but the one we planning to do cloud to cloud that is AWS to AZURE and main database we have AWS Redshift on AWS and that we want to migrate to AZure.

Comment: Follow this document
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/migrate-tutorial-aws-azure

Comment: Thanks but this is for instance to migrate. We want postgres Database to be migrated to Azure

Comment: You can use Azure Database Migration Service